# viewport shading solid is showing wireframe or similar

Tags: edit-mode

One of my objects is showing a wireframe or similar.  I have looked at view-port shading options but I didnt see anything that could influence it. Is this  a bug?

[image]

Comment: maybe check the Object panel > Viewport Display > Display As?

Comment: @moonboots: That also does not work.

Comment: could you please share this object?

Comment: Attach the .blend file here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem.
I imported an object via stl and deleted faces/edges and not realising that my remaining vertices were not connected at all. Then it remained a wireframe after a screw modifier.

Solution:
Select vertices of interest to connect and press F. Then X and select "only face". It should leave vertices/edges.
It will now become visible after a screw modifier.